# What is the e-mail address of Stack Overflow notifications?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, email, email-notification

I accidentally clicked on "Delete and block" for an SO notification in my Hotmail account. I would like to unblock SO, but can't find the e-mail address.

Answer (score 3):

I know for meta it is:
**do-not-reply@meta.stackoverflow.com**

I'm going to go out on a limb and guess stackoverflow itself is:
**do-not-reply@stackoverflow.com**

Comment: lol, i can't find it in my blocked senders too. Anyway i hv added it to my safe senders list. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Emails from the new global notification system are sent from  `do-not-reply@stackexchange.com`.